# Nuxt Bridge : alternative to `useFetch()` in @nuxtjs/composition-api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I'm migrating from `@nuxtjs/composition-api` package to [Nuxt Bridge](https://github.com/nuxt/bridge) and I see that `useFetch` is available **only** with Nuxt 3.

Before, I was using the pattern below:

```js
const { state: userState, getUserList } = useUserList()
const { state: groupState, getGroupList } = useGroupList()    
// ...

const { fetchState } = useFetch(async () => {
 await Promise.all([
   getUserList(),
   getGroupList(),
   // ...
 ])
})
```

And I could use `fetchState.pending` to display a loader until everything was loaded.

How to have the behavior with Nuxt Bridge knowing that only `useLazyAsyncData` and `useLazyFetch` are compatible?

Comment: Could use Options API IMO.

Comment: @kissu `async fetch() {}``` from the option API you mean?

Comment: @kissu For the moment i use `useLazyAsyncData` without returning anything and with option `{server: false}`.

Comment: Yeah, that or `asyncData` depending on how you want it to be behave in your app (blocking or non blocking client side navigation).